# Converting a number to two decimal places

Tags: javascript

I have a number

```
num = 0.99922312
```

I would like to shorten it to just 0.99. I thought I could do this with a simple toFixed

```
num.toFixed(2)
```

However this just returns the value of 
`1.00`. I've also tried a bunch of decimal combinations such as .toFixed(2.2) and so on.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Kind of I guess but seems such a backwards way. I would need to convert the number to a string, slice it, and then back to a number again? Fair dos. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: `toFixed` creates a string too. Why are you truncating it if not for purposes of displaying it? Only thing that comes to mind is currency calculations but you should be using a specialized library for that.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Thanks, I didn't actually realise that toFixed also created a string. It's tensorflow prediction results that I'm getting from the back end and then sorting in react front end by the prediction number. The number is also displayed.

Comment: @alienbuild Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply convert the number to a string, get the index of the decimal point, and use slice to remove all the characters after the first two characters after the decimal point.

```js
function truncate(num){
    var str = num.toString();
    var idx = str.indexOf('.');
    return idx != -1 ? str.slice(0, idx + 3): str;
}
console.log(0.99922312, "->", truncate(0.99922312));
console.log(0.8, "->", truncate(0.8));
console.log(0.121, "->", truncate(0.121));
console.log(0.235, "->", truncate(0.235));
console.log(12, "->", truncate(12));
```

If you need the truncated result as a number instead of a string, you can use the unary plus operator to convert it back to a number.

```
var truncatedNum = +truncate(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way:

```js
var num = 0.99922312
var twoDecimals = num.toString().substring(0, 4)
console.log(twoDecimals)
```

Comment: Don't use `new` for primitive types.

Comment: This approach is non-generalized: `num = 1234.56` -> `1234` (0 decimals), `num = 123.456` -> `123.` (0 decimals, dangling dot), `num = 12345` -> `1234` (oops)  etc.